# upload csv file using ajax call to controller mvc c# not working on uat server

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, csv, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to upload .csv file into my application. the code is woking properly at my local pc. but it gives me an error related to jquery when i deployed the same code on my UAT server.

The error details are as follow,

- POST https://www.dummy.com/Customers/UploadCustomersLead 404 (Not
  Found)
- send @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4
- ajax @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4
- (anonymous) @ Customers:592
- dispatch @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3
- r.handle @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3

my controller code is as follow,

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadCustomersLead()
{
    string sMessage = "";
    bool bStatus = true;
    bool bError = false;

    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new    System.IO.StreamWriter(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFile"].ToString());
    file.WriteLine("inside upload cust");

    var attachedFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["CsvDoc"];
    if (attachedFile != null && attachedFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(attachedFile.FileName);
        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(ConfigManager.GetUploadCSVFilePathForUpload), fileName);

        file.WriteLine("inside upload cust path:" + path);
        try
        {
            attachedFile.SaveAs(path);
            DataTable dt = ConvertCSVToDataTable(path); //DataTable dt = CommonFunction.ConvertCSVToDataTable(path); //Are not working because this method is in PNRMSystem.BLL/CommonBusinessLogic.cs file.

            List<string> l = new List<string>();
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MerchantMasterService.MerchantMasterClient merchantMasterClient = new MerchantMasterService.MerchantMasterClient();
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    MerchantMasterService.AddCustomerLeadsFromAdminRequest addCustomerLeadsFromMerchantDashboardRequest = new MerchantMasterService.AddCustomerLeadsFromAdminRequest
                    {
                        RegisteredMobileNumber = row["SellerNumber"].ToString(),         //MerchantMobileNumber;
                        CustomerMobileNumber = row["CustomerNumber"].ToString(),         //CustomerMobileNumber,
                        CustomerName = row["CustomerName"].ToString(),                   //CustomerName,
                        Address = row["Address"].ToString(),                             //Address,
                        BillAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(row["BillAmount"].ToString())     //BillAmount
                    };
                                                                                                                                                                                                         MerchantMasterService.AddCustomerLeadsFromAdminResponse addCustomerLeadsFromMerchantDashboardResponse = merchantMasterClient.AddCustomerLeadsFromAdmin(addCustomerLeadsFromMerchantDashboardRequest);
                    if  (addCustomerLeadsFromMerchantDashboardResponse.StatusCode.ToString().ToLower().Equals("failure"))
                    {
                        l.Add(row["CustomerNumber"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            dt.Dispose();
            ModelState.Clear();
            var Number = l.Count > 0 ? string.Join(",", l) : "None";
            sMessage = "Total Records : " + dt.Rows.Count + "</br>" + "Total Success : " + (dt.Rows.Count - l.Count) + "<br/>" + "Total failure : " + l.Count + "<br/>" + "Total failure Number : " + Number;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             ModelState.AddModelError("File", ex.Message.ToString());
             CreateLog.Error(this.GetType(), "Error occured on UploadCustomersLead action in Customers controller in merchant dashboard.", ex);
             bError = true;
             sMessage = "An error occured. Please try again.";
             throw;
        }
        finally
        {
             if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
             {
                 System.IO.File.Delete(path);
             }
             file.Close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Please Select Your file");
    }
    return Json(new { Message = sMessage, Status = bStatus, Error = bError }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and .cshtml file jquery code is as follow,

```
$("#btnUploadCustLeads").click(function () {
                var fileExtension = ['csv'];
                if ($("#IDofTheUploader").val() == "" || $("#IDofTheUploader").val() == null || $.inArray($("#IDofTheUploader").val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
                    $('#statusBoxUploadCustLeads').removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success').show(500, function () {
                        $('#statusMessageUploadCustLeads').html("Kindly select the .csv file to be uploaded.");
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $('#imgLoadingAddCustomer').removeAttr("style");
                    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("IDofTheUploader");
                    if (fileUpload.value != null) {
                        var uploadFile = new FormData();
                        var files = $("#IDofTheUploader").get(0).files;
                        // Add the uploaded file content to the form data collection
                        if (files.length > 0) {
                            uploadFile.append("CsvDoc", files[0]);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "/Customers/UploadCustomersLead",
                                contentType: false,
                                processData: false,
                                data: uploadFile,
                                type: 'POST',
                                success: function (data) {
                                    $('#statusBoxUploadCustLeads').removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success').show(500, function () {
                                        $('#statusMessageUploadCustLeads').html(data.Message);
                                        ClearUploadCustLeadsControls();
                                    });
                                },
                                complete: function () {
                                    $('#imgLoadingAddCustomer').css("display", "none");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#statusBoxUploadCustLeads').removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success').show(500, function () {
                            $('#statusMessageUploadCustLeads').html("File to be uploaded can not be bank.");
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: url: "/Customers/UploadCustomersLead", do not use absolute url. "~/Customers/UploadCustomersLead"

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but I have insufficient rep.

Try checking the route configuration of the UAT server. I had similar errors when I had multiple GET methods on a controller - I needed to specify a route which took the method name as an argument using something like this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "CallMethodByName",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

If this piece of configuration is not in the UAT server it won't handle the request properly and return a 404 error.

EDIT: The new config should go below the older one (more specific instructions should go later). This should work with post as well as get methods. How does your test config compare to the UAT config?

Answer (score 0):

@princeofmince , I have tried route configuration with

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "CallMethodByName",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

in routeconfig.cs file on server but didn't work and my action method is of **[httppost]** method not **[httpget]**